# Почему получаются разная форма дуги при значении 0 или 1 атрибута large-arc-flag?

Tags: svg

**large-arc-flag** при значении 1

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke='black' width='500' height='200' style='border: 1px solid black;'>
 <path d="M 70 70 A 70 70 0 1 1 150 150" />
</svg>
```

**large-arc-flag** при значении 0

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke='black' width='500' height='200' style='border: 1px solid black;'>
 <path d="M 70 70 A 70 70 0 0 1 150 150" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного теории:

```
<path d="M mx,my A rx,ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag, sweep-flag x,y" />
```

Более подробно о значениях параметров [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=900)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите из картинки, результирующая дуга получается в результате пересечения двух окружностей.  Но вот по какому пути она пойдёт от стартовой точки - `Arc start` до финальной - `Arc end`, зависит, как раз от параметров `large-arc-flag` и `sweep-flag`

**large-arc-flag** – параметр, отвечающий за вывод большей части дуги, если **(=1)** или меньшей **(=0)**

**sweep-flag** – отвечает за направление отрисовки дуги из начальной точки в конечную точку. Если `sweep-flag=1`, то дуга эллипса будет отрисована по часовой стрелке. При `sweep-flag=0` – против часовой стрелки.

Ваш пример:

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke='black' width='500' height='200' style='border: 1px solid black;'>
 <path d="M 70 70 A 70 70 0 1 1 150 150" />
</svg>
```

`large-arc-flag = "1", sweep-flag="1"` - расшифровываем:    дуга пойдет от стартовой точки к финальной по большому пути, по часовой стрелке.
На картинке это вариант **(e)**

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke='black' width='500' height='200' style='border: 1px solid black;'>
 <path d="M 70 70 A 70 70 0 0 1 150 150" />
</svg>
```

Малая дуга - `large-arc-flag = 0`

По часовой стрелке - `sweep-flag = 1`

Вариант **(С)** на рисунке